# TypeError: Object of type Asia/Kolkata is not JSON serializable

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use timezone_field, but it shows it is not serializable and shows error.

Please need your help. I have provided code in below..

Thanks in advance.

### Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from timezone_field import TimeZoneField
# Create your models here.
class Member(models.Model):
   tz = TimeZoneField(default='Asia/Kolkata')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.tz
```

### serializers.py

```
from . models import Member
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

class Member_Serializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'
```

### views.py

```
from . models import Member
from . serializers import Member_Serializer
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView
# Create your views here.
class MemberListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = Member_Serializer
```

### error:

```
Object of type Asia/Kolkata is not JSON serializable
         Request Method:    POST
         Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/a/
         Django Version:    3.1.1
         Exception Type:    TypeError
         Exception Value:   
            Object of type Asia/Kolkata is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the serialization behaviour for the **`tz`** field

```
from .models import Member
from rest_framework import serializers


class Member_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tz = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Great Sir.. Thanks for this.. It helps me to serialize..